# Apache Commons Mail: how get new line in simple email?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Silly newbie question. I can generate an email message body using,

```
email.setMsg("Paragraph 1 goes here.");
```

which outputs:

```
Paragraph 1 goes here.
```

Now what I want to generate looks like:

```
Paragraph 1 goes here.
Paragraph 2 goes here.
```

But if I use:

```
email.setMsg("Paragraph 1 goes here."); 
email.setMsg("Paragraph 2 goes here.");
```

All I get is:

```
Paragraph 2 goes here.
```

How to add manual line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on UNIX system:

```
email.setMsg("Paragraph 1 goes here.\nParagraph 2 goes here.");
```

To make the code platform agnostic you can lookup the linebreak using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`:

```
String ENDL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
email.setMsg("Paragraph 1 goes here." + ENDL + "Paragraph 2 goes here.");
```

If you use HTML email:

```
email.setMsg("<p>Paragraph 1 goes here.</p><p>Paragraph 2 goes here.</p>");
```

Comment: in HTML email, <br> should do as suggested in other posts.